# How can I define multiple xml namespaces in package annotation in java

Tags: java, jaxb, annotations, xsd

For my web service, I have defined the request and response XML structures in java classes in a package, I use `@XmlElement` annotations.

I have also a `package-info.java` file defining `@XmlSchema` for the whole package and **also defining what the prefix for the XML elements should be**:

```
@XmlSchema(namespace = XmlNamespace.MY_SERVICE,
  xmlns = { @XmlNs(namespaceURI = XmlNamespace.MY_SERVICE, prefix = "ser")},
  elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
```

The problem is: I use 2 namespaces for the request, so I want some of the XML elements with prefix `<ser:element1>` and others with `<req:element2>`.
The generated wsdl and request already gave me 2 different prefixes, but the second prefix is not the one I want – “req”.

How can I achieve this? I tried with

```
@XmlSchema(namespace = XmlNamespace.MY_SERVICE,
  xmlns = { @XmlNs(namespaceURI = XmlNamespace.MY_SERVICE, prefix = "ser"),
        @XmlNs(namespaceURI = XmlNamespace.MY_SERVICE_XSD, prefix = "per2")},
  elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
```

but it’s not working.

Comment: Here is a link to a blog post I wrote about JAXB and namespaces:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html